# Как в Twisted вызвать sendMessage функцию из другого класса?

Tags: python, python-2.x, twisted

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ICQ bot

import os
import re
import sys
from twisted.words.protocols import oscar
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

# UIN
UIN = "658127246"
PASS = "p@$$w0rd"

# Server
host = ("login.icq.com", 5190)
icqMode = 1

# Status message
AMSG = "I'm here +)"


class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print data
        try:
            finded = re.findall(r"(?P<name>.*?): '(?P<value>.*?)'; ", data)
            data2 = dict(finded)
            sendTo = data2['SendTo']
            msg = data2['MSG']
        except:
            sendTo = '881129'
            msg = '=> error receive data message <='
        response = 'Send to UIN: %s\r\nMessage: %s\r\n\r\n' % (sendTo, msg)
        self.transport.write(response)
        # Как от сюда вызвать sendMessage(sendTo, msg) ?????

class B(oscar.BOSConnection):

    capabilities = [oscar.CAP_CHAT]

    def initDone(self):
        print "Connect ",UIN," to server", host[0], host[1]
        self.requestSelfInfo().addCallback(self.gotSelfInfo)
        self.requestSSI().addCallback(self.gotBuddyList)
        self.setAway(AMSG)
        factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
        factory.protocol = Echo
        reactor.listenTCP(8007, factory)

    def gotSelfInfo(self, user):
        print user.__dict__
        self.name = user.name

    def gotBuddyList(self, l):
        print l
        self.activateSSI()
        self.setProfile("""ICQBot for Lead4CRM""")
        self.setIdleTime(0)
        self.clientReady()
        # self.sendICQMessage()

    def gotAway(self, away, user):
        if away:
            print "User ", user,": ",away

    def toUnicodeOrBust(self, obj, encoding='utf-8'):
        if isinstance(obj, basestring):
            if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
                obj = unicode(obj, encoding)
        return obj


class OA(oscar.OscarAuthenticator):
    print 'Start ICQ connection'
    print 'pid: ', os.getpid()
    BOSClass = B


if __name__ == '__main__':
    protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, OA, UIN, PASS, icq=icqMode).connectTCP(*host)
    # reactor.callLater(10, reactor.stop)
    reactor.run()

    sys.exit()
```

Я не знаю как вызвать метод `sendMessage`. Банальное `B().sendMessage()` вываливает ошибку:

`exceptions.TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`

Изучение исходников дало понимание, что в вызываемый класс `B()` надо передать `username` и `cookie`. Если с `username` еще как-то понятно, то вот с `cookie` не понятно совсем, что за кулисы и откуда их брать.

Comment: *"Сообщения не отправляются и я не знаю в чем моя ошибка."* + куча кода без разбора—не очень информативно. Попробуйте начать с минимального самодостаточного скрипта, который работает и постепенно добавляйте код, чтобы реализовать нужную вам функциональность пока он не сломается. Опишите подробно действия, которые приводят к ошибке (по шагам): что вы ожидали получить? Что вместо этого происходит (что в логи пишется? если есть сообщения, то их нужно привести). См. [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jfs изменил код, убрал лишнее, корректно задал вопрос, внес некоторые уточнения.

Comment: Не стоит чуть вопроса кардинально менять (ответов нет пока—поэтому изменения как есть можно оставить).  На будущее: "как послать ICQ сообщение используя twisted", "как вызвать `sendMessage()`", и "что такое (http) cookie и где его взять" это разные вопросы, которые лучше отдельно задавать (для контекста можно ссылаться внутри одного вопроса на другой—но вопросы должны быть самодостаточны).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать при создании `factory` в `B.initDone()` передать `self` (`B` тип) в `Echo` (`__init__` метод написать) или передать в `factory` напрямую (присвоить атрибут или создать свой `Factory` класс c `__init__` методом). Тогда в `Echo.dataReceived()` не нужно `B()` создавать, а использовать переданный экземпляр.